# How to prevent superscripts from moving under \sqrt?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

When I put an expression with superscripts under a `\sqrt`, the superscripts (here "vis") move down a bit. How can I prevent that, so that it looks consistent no matter whether it's under a root or not?

[image]

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[  (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2  \]
\[  \sqrt{ (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2}  \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

LaTeX knows eight math styles, four main ones and four secondary. They are called `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. In general TeX chooses automatically the right style. In some constructions it uses the secondary style, frequently called the “cramped version”.

For instance, when typesetting a fraction when the current style is `\displaystyle`, TeX will choose `\textstyle` for the numerator and the cramped version for the denominator. Similarly, what's under a radical is typeset in the cramped version of the current style.

The “cramped” version is so called because exponents are set lower than in the uncramped style, which is exactly the problem you are seeing. This is automatic, so you need to override the style selection manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[  (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2  \]
\[  \sqrt{ (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2}  \]
\[  \sqrt{\displaystyle (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2}  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice! But the question based on your statement *This is automatic* is: why?

Comment: @Sigur Because Knuth so decreed.

Comment: oh, in this case, we must accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Put the intermediate result in a box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[  (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2  \]
\[  \sqrt{ (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2}  \]
\newsavebox\tempbox
\sbox\tempbox{$\displaystyle(E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2$}
\[ \sqrt{\usebox\tempbox} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It also works without the box, what does the trick is the `\displaystyle` command: `\sqrt{ \displaystyle (E^\mathrm{vis}_x)^2 + (E^\mathrm{vis}_y)^2}`.

Comment: @jdm Even better answer than mine.  You should post your own result as an answer and accept that as the preferable one.

Comment: I found that solution just a minute after writing the question, but didn't post it immediately because I was hoping that someone would explain *how* it works. Also its too late, egreg was too fast :-) *and* added an explanation.