# Is it possible to make siunitx typeset exponents in "cramped" style?

Tags: spacing, luatex, siunitx, unicode-math

I'm using [siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to typeset physical quantities. The result is not always ideal with many exponents in my eyes, because the exponents increase the line to line distance. At least this is my impression. I haven't measured it to be honest. For example take a look on this image:

[image]

The first two values are set with the default settings of `siunitx`. There is much white space around them alienating them from the rest of the text. My current approach is to take the `text mode` option. With the (smaller) old style figures the result looks more harmonious. Now I learned [here on tex.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154480/3061) that it is possible to cramp the exponents. As you can see in the example (the last to values), this results to a more homogenious appearance.

Coming to my question, is it possible to configure `siunitx` in a way that it cramps the exponents?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage{microtype}

\def\sometext{ Some text, which takes roughly one line. This sentence is used
    to demonstrate different line spacing due to the use of scientific value,
    such as }

\begin{document}

\sometext
\SI{1.23E13}{\per\square\centi\metre\per\electronvolt}
here. \sometext
\SI{1.23E13}{\per\square\centi\metre\per\electronvolt}
here. \sometext
\SI[mode = text]{1.23E13}{\per\square\centi\metre\per\electronvolt}
here. \sometext
\SI[mode = text]{1.23E13}{\per\square\centi\metre\per\electronvolt}
here. \sometext
$1.23\times\cramped{10^{13}}\,\cramped{\text{cm}^{-2}}\,\text{eV}\cramped{^{-1}}$
here. \sometext
$1.23\times\cramped{10^{13}}\,\cramped{\text{cm}^{-2}}\,\text{eV}\cramped{^{-1}}$
here. \sometext 
{1.23~$\times$~10⁻¹³\,cm⁻²\,eV⁻¹}
here. \sometext no value here. 
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I've added a pure (unicode) text variant using unicode superscripts, unfortunately TG Pagella does not have a superscript minus sign.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I don't think it's wise to use text-style (aka oldstyle) numerals in subscripts and superscripts. If you look at font families that provide numerals designed specifically for typesetting in raised and lowered positions, they are without exception "lining" figures.

Comment: @Mico, true. And I also think that it is not common practice to use old style numerals at all for scientific values, although I've seen an journal which does this. I added an example which shows why it is not possible to use the unicode superscripts.

Comment: @Mico, I'm actually using Pagella in my working document and I like it's high black/white ratio, but I will give the increased linespacing a trial.

Comment: I just figured out a solution and am about to post a full answer.

Comment: @mico The you mustn't have studied the _LaTeX and Friends_ copy I sent you:-) Admitted, the result wasn't ideal because I used the `mathastext` package to configure the math fonts. However, IMHO oldstyle sub and superscripts don't look that bad. I think it's something you have to get used to. I think it's more important the figures for the subscripts/superscripts are _tabular._

Comment: @MarcvanDongen - I do still have your book -- on my desk! :-) I looked at chapters 8 and 9 just now for a refresher. If I came across as claiming that oldstyle figures should not be used *under any circumstance* in mathematics, I'll admit to having gone a bit too far. However, unless I missed it, you wisely stayed away from typesetting expressions such as `a^{36}`, `10^{46}`, and `b_{27}`: having a number that simultaneously contains numerals that either fall below the baseline or rise above the x-height line can confuse easily, esp. if the numbers occur in sub- or superscript positions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're using LuaLaTeX, you could execute the command

```
\everymath{\crampedtextstyle}
```

This instruction tells TeX to use "cramped" style automatically whenever it's in inline math mode -- as is the case when `\SI{...}{...}` is processed.

The command `\crampedtextstyle`, a "primitive" command, instructs LuaTeX to position first- and second-level superscripts in cramped mode. The macro `\everymath` tells TeX to execute `\crampedtextstyle` whenever it is in inline-math mode -- but not in display-math mode, when you presumably don't have a need for the "cramped" math style.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx,mathtools,unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\SI{1.23E13}{\per\square\centi\metre\per\electronvolt}

\everymath{\crampedtextstyle}
\SI{1.23E13}{\per\square\centi\metre\per\electronvolt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this will also change inline math equations, but I think that's a good idea anyway.

Comment: BTW, I'm using `lualatex` instead of `xelatex` because of your `selnolig` package :)

Comment: @quinmars - If using cramped style in conjunction with `\SI{...}{...}` is a good idea, using cramped style is probably a good style in other inline-math situations too, right? :-)

Comment: @quinmars - And thanks for the compliment about `selnolig`!!

Comment: right! There it is not a real problem since I rarely use inline math with capitals and superscripts, else I probably had ask a different questions with the same answer. ;-)

Comment: I have to thank. The `selnolig` is a nice package. You should sell it to _surkamp_, I'm reading a book of them currently and I'm really annoyed of their wrong usage of ligatures.