# Subscript not aligned when there is superscript

Tags: vertical-alignment, subscripts, superscripts

For example, `A_{P_{i+1} P'_{i+1} P'_i}` gives me something like this:

[image]

Right now I just add `^{ }` to the first P to solve this problem. This there a systematic way to deal with this?

Comment: It is possible you have run into an issue with "cramped version" math style, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154474/how-to-prevent-superscripts-from-moving-under-sqrt/154480#154480

Comment: There are probably far more cases when such alignment is not necessary (or even unwanted), so there is no "systematic way" of dealing with this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real systematic way of dealing with this, unless you wrap your scripting into macro-form where you can place content in a more consistent way.

Moreover, this is probably not something that happens often, so some manual intervention via `\vphantom` takes care of the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$A_{P_{i+1} P'_{i+1} P'_i}$

$A_{P^{\prime}_{i+1} P'_{i+1} P'_i}$

$A_{P^{\vphantom{\prime}}_{i+1} P'_{i+1} P'_i}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that `\vphantom{\prime}` is necessary: `A_{P^{}_{i+1}}` should suffice.

Comment: I would imagine something like `A_1 A'_1` appears in a lot of places, and it looks really weird if the two 1 are not aligned. Anyway, if there is not systematic solution. I will settle on adding a `^{}`

Comment: @auzn: The "operand"/base `A` on the left might be completely different (even in size) from the `A` on the right in general. Manual intervention with `^{}` or another `\phantom`-like composition is often how this is fixed.