# Behaviour of \sqrt

Tags: math-mode

I compile the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \[
    K^\times \quad
    \lvert K^\times \rvert \quad
    \sqrt{\lvert K^\times\rvert} \quad
    \sqrt{ K^\times }
    \]

    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

    \[
    K^\times \quad
    \lvert K^\times \rvert \quad
    \sqrt{\lvert K^\times\rvert} \quad
    \sqrt{ K^\times }
    \]
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

**Question 1:** Why is the `\times` set lower if there is a `\sqrt` around it? I want it to be typeset as if there was no square root, having a taller square root symbol if necessary.

**Question 2:** If I choose another math font, why is the square root taller if I leave out the absolute value?

Comment: Arguments of e.g. `\sqrt` are typeset in the so-called "cramped" style. The first question is probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154474/82917. For the second question, note that also in CM the square root is taller because of the depth of the absolute value. Choosing different fonts (which have different width/height/depth/skew) features can give different result. That happens almost always.

Comment: I don’t think that the square root sign is taller when you leave out the absolute value, I think it is simply moved up a bit.

Comment: \mathmbox{K^\times} works, but is incompatible with unicode-math.